# Can I use two post method api for a method?

Tags: angular, nodemailer

I am trying to register the user and at the same time send an email when the register button is clicked.

**Component**

```js
register() {
this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(this.token);
    this.toast.setMessage('you successfully registered!', 'success');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  },
  error => this.toast.setMessage('email already exists', 'danger')
);
}
```

**Service**

```js
register(user): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post('/api/user', JSON.stringify(user), this.options);
}
```

**Node Mailer API**

```js
var headers = new Headers();
var creds = 'emailid=' + user.email ;
var emailid = 'emailid=' + user.email;

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');


  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail', emailid, {headers: headers}).subscribe((data) => {
  if(data.json().success) {
    console.log('Sent successfully');
  }
})
```

I want the mail API to come under register method. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the code that you use for sending mail under the success callback for register:

Component :

```
this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail', emailid, {headers: headers}).subscribe((data) => {
      if(data.json().success) {
        console.log('Sent successfully');
      }
    })
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  },
  error => this.toast.setMessage('email already exists', 'danger')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
  register() {
this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(this.token);
    this.toast.setMessage('you successfully registered!', 'success');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  },
  error => this.toast.setMessage('email already exists', 'danger')
);  
this.userService.email(this.registerForm.value);
}
```

Service

```
  register(user): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post('/api/user', JSON.stringify(user), this.options);
}

 email(user){
var headers = new Headers();
var creds = 'emailid=' + user.email ;
var emailid = 'emailid=' + user.email;

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');


      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail', emailid, {headers: headers}).subscribe((data) => {
  if(data.json().success) {
    console.log('Sent successfully');
  }
})
}
```